# Debugging Web-Applications on Android

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, console

I'm developing a web-application for iPhone and Android. It works flawlessly on the iPhone but when I try to run it on an Android device, it just does not work.

**But to the point… I need to access the (JavaScript) error console** in the Android *default browser*. Is there a way to do that?

I tried changing the "Enable tracing" setting after accessing the hidden `about:debug` menu in the browser but nothing seems to change.

UPDATE: by the way, I'm using the Android Virtual Device software from the Android SDK.